# Event handler not always called

Tags: c#, events, handler

I have custom thread which parses WiFi networks and updates the UI (DataGridView and graphs). Here is the thread method:

```
private void RefreshThread()
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
        UpdateAllNetworks();
        UpdateAllInterferences();
        UpdateAllColors();

        switch (ActivePage)
        {
            case Page.Start:
                break;
            case Page.Networks:
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    UpdateDataGridWithNetworks();
                    ClearGraphs();
                    Draw24GHzGraph();
                    DrawSignalsOverTimeGraph();
                });
                break;
            case Page.Channels:
                break;
            case Page.Analyze:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        int elapsedMs = (int) watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (elapsedMs < Constants.NetworksRefreshThreadInterval)
            Thread.Sleep(Constants.NetworksRefreshThreadInterval - elapsedMs);
    }
}
```

Custom DataGridView:

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
...
    protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellClick(e);
        int Index = e.RowIndex;

        if (Index != -1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = Rows[Index];
            PrimaryKeyForSelectedRow = row.Cells[KeyName].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The DataGridView is my custom DataGrid where I have a click event handler. I have observed that sometimes the event handler isn't called but in most cases it is.

What could be the problem? Is it related to multithreading or the event isn't queued?

Comment: What event handler isn't called? I don't see an event handler.

Comment: Do other GUI actions work, eg. resize, drag?

Comment: No because I disabled it. On the DataGridView you can only select the row.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the thread?

Comment: This thread is the main part of the application, if I disable it the DataGrid wouldn't be filled and there would be nothing to select.

Answer (score 0):

Your code blocks main thread, use separate thread for your network details update. Here is quick sample how it done.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var helper = new Looper(5000, YourMethod_RefreshThread);
        helper.Start();
    }

    private static void YourMethod_RefreshThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}

public class Looper
{
    private readonly Action _callback;
    private readonly int _interval;

    public Looper(int interval, Action callback)
    {
        if(interval <=0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("interval");
        }
        if(callback == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
        }
        _interval = interval;
        _callback = callback;
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        var next = Environment.TickCount;

        do
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount >= next)
            {
                _callback();
                next = Environment.TickCount + _interval;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(_interval);

        } while (IsRunning);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            return;
        }
        var thread = new Thread(Work);
        thread.Start();
        IsRunning = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.IsRunning = false;
    }

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }
```

Comment: RefreshThread() is a separate thread called  `Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate { RefreshThread(); });`